# How to calculate moving avarage within array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sorting, average

I have a table with two columns, id and for each id an array with values. I want to calculate the moving avarage within the id over the moving 3 elements.

| id | v |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {210,200,180,120,150,200} |
| 2 | {230,180,140,100,170,210} |

```
create table series(id int, v _int4);

insert into series 
values(1,array[210,200,180,120,150,200])
        ,(2,array[230,180,140,100,170,210]);
```

If i use the following query it works for one id

```
select id, nr, "elemV",  avg("elemV") over (order by nr rows between 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "movingAvgOver3elements"
from series t, unnest("v") with ordinality as a("elemV", nr) 
where id = 1 ;
```

| id | nr | elemV | movingAvgOverLast4Elements |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 210 | 210.0000000000000000 |
| 1 | 2 | 200 | 205.0000000000000000 |
| 1 | 3 | 180 | 196.6666666666666667 |
| 1 | 4 | 120 | 177.5000000000000000 |
| 1 | 5 | 150 | 162.5000000000000000 |
| 1 | 6 | 200 | 162.5000000000000000 |

How does it works for all id's within the id ?

The problem is in that case the 4 elements moving over the id 1 to 2

```
    select id, nr, "elemV",  avg("elemV") over (order by id, nr rows between 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "movingAvgOver3elements"
    from series t, unnest("v") with ordinality as a("elemV", nr)
```

| id | nr | elemV | movingAvgOver3elements |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 210 | 210.0000000000000000 |
| 1 | 2 | 200 | 205.0000000000000000 |
| 1 | 3 | 180 | 196.6666666666666667 |
| 1 | 4 | 120 | 177.5000000000000000 |
| 1 | 5 | 150 | 162.5000000000000000 |
| 1 | 6 | 200 | 162.5000000000000000 |
| 2 | 1 | 230 | 175.0000000000000000 |
| 2 | 2 | 180 | 190.0000000000000000 |
| 2 | 3 | 140 | 187.5000000000000000 |
| 2 | 4 | 100 | 162.5000000000000000 |
| 2 | 5 | 170 | 147.5000000000000000 |
| 2 | 6 | 210 | 155.0000000000000000 |

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, I think you just need to add a PARTITION BY clause to make each id a separate frame.  With that clause in place, you can also remove the sort by id, although that's optional.

```
select id, nr, "elemV",  avg("elemV") over (PARTITION BY id order by nr rows between 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "movingAvgOver3elements"
    from series t, unnest("v") with ordinality as a("elemV", nr);
```